# Ankylosing Spondylitis early diagnosis

Tags: prevention, spine, weather

My girlfriend is 22 and has a condition of ankylosing spondylitis. She has to take pain killers every day, especially when the weather is more humid or cold, otherwise her lower back keeps hurting. She complained recently of feeling like she's losing a bit of flexibility in that area, which is associated with the condition.

The [following article](http://www.healthline.com/health-slideshow/ankylosing-spondylitis-remission#3) from Health Line says the following:

> Remission is also a treatment goal. To go into remission from AS, the
>   inflammatory response it causes must be dampened and controlled with
>   medications.

I've looked online for all resource I can find and recent advancements on treatments for it, and I am looking for any further guidance on how to slow/reverse as much as possible the effects of that condition.

E.g. sports that can be practised, food that can be eaten, additional vitamins that can be taken, operations that can be done. It appears that the objective of treating this condition is to reduce inflammation to reach a low level of disease activity. Any advice is most welcome. Any further explanation of how that condition develops is also most welcome.

Comment: is she HLAB27 positive ?  Best way to take control of your pain is to perform yoga.

Comment: @Bugfixer After verifying the most recent blood test it says HLA-B27 is negative/normal and ESR1 and ESR2 says high. The test is 2 years old. Thank you for the yoga tip.

Comment: I'm sorry, but medical advice is off topic here. We can answer any factual questions you have about AS, but we can't provide advice.